# Will adding a middle name to a new passport cause issues with a US visa?

Tags: visas, usa, passports

My son's old passport has name as Advaith Jidigi and I want to add middle name as Varma, so the name becomes Advaith Varma Jidigi. I hold a valid US visa. Will there be any problem entering the US with his new passport that includes his middle name?

Comment: Why change the name in the passport? It is much easier not to change it.

Comment: Was the middle name part of the son's name all along, but somehow didn't get into the old passport, or are you adding it to the son's name for the first time? Are asking if a change to the son's name will make it difficult for you to enter the US? Is the son coming to the US?

Comment: Will the old passport have to be relinquished when the new one is issued? From [I changed my name. Is my U.S. visa with my old name still valid?](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html)
>If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from the United States.